# Solve for $x$ in the following trigonometric equation: $3\cot^2(x) = 1$ in the domain $x$ is an element of $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

**My question lies in the third step of my solution, is taking the square root of the term $\cot^2(x)$ valid?**

$$\cot^2 x = 1/3$$

$$\cot^2 x = (\cot x)^2$$

Which implies

$$ \sqrt{\cot x}^2 = \sqrt{1/3}$$

Thus, $\cot(x) = 1/\sqrt3$

Since $\cot(x) = ADJ/OPP$

we know $x = \pi/3$

Comment: Not quite. You have $\cot x = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so there are two possible values of $\cot x$. Additionally, for each of those values, there are two possible values of $x$, so in the end you should get four possible answers in $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: So $x = PI/3,  2PI/3,   4PI/3,   5PI/3$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have square of any Trigonometric Ratio, convert it to double angle of cosine

$$\cos2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{\cot^2x-1}{\cot^2x+1}=-\frac12=-\cos\frac\pi3$$

But $-\cos y=\cos\left(\pi-y\right)$

$$\implies\cos2x=\cos\frac{2\pi}3\implies2x=2m\pi\pm\frac{2\pi}3=\frac{2\pi}3(3m\pm1)\iff x=\frac\pi3(3m\pm1)$$ where $m$ is any integer

Now choose $n$ such that $0\le\dfrac\pi3(3m\pm1)\le2\pi\iff0\le3m\pm1\le6$